# silverstripe 3 addFieldToTab "Settings"

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I want to add a Field to the existing Tab "Settings" of Edit Page View (marked in the screenshot).

I tried this:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Settings', new TextField('Intro'));
```

But it just adds a new tab next to the secondary Tab "Main Content" containing the additional Field.

[image: Silverstripe Edid Page View]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For SilverStripe 3.0 you need to override the [getSettingsFields()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/cms/SiteTree.html#methodgetSettingsFields) function in your Model e.g.

```
function getSettingsFields() {
    $fields = parent::getSettingsFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Settings", new TextField('Intro'));
    return $fields;
}
```

In SilverStripe 2.x this is done in the getCMSFields() function.

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me:

```
public function updateSettingsFields(FieldList $fields) {
  $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.MyNewSettingsSubTab", new TextField('Intro'));
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Just worth noting you'd use this method if doing via a ```DataExtension```, however if you're doing it via a class that extends from ```Page``` the first answer is what you'd use.